# How can semaphores implemented on multi-core systems?

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix, semaphore

I can not understand how Posix allows any thread to unlock (post) on a semaphore. Let's consider following example:

```
// sem1 and sem2 are a Posix semaphore,
// properly initialized for single process use
// at this point, sem2 is locked, sem1 is unlocked 
// x and y are global (non-atomic, non-volatile) integer variables
// thread 1 - is executing right now

rc = sem_wait(&sem1); // succeeded, semaphore is 0 now
x = 42;
y = 142;
sem_post(&sem2);
while (true);

// thread 2. waits for sem2 to be unlocked by thread1 
sem_wait(&sem2);
sem_post(&sem1);

// thread 3
sem_wait(&sem1); // wakes up when sem1 is unlocked by thread2
#ifdef __cplusplus
std::cout << "x: " << x << ; y: " << y << "\n";
#else
printf("x: %d; y: %d\n", x, y);
#endif
```

Now, according to everything I've read, this code is 100% kosher for passover. In thread 3, we are guaranteed to see `x` as 42,  `y` as 142. We are proteced from any race.

But this is what I can't understand. All those threads can potentially be executed on 3 different cores. And if the chip doesn't have internally strong memory ordering (ARM, PowerPC) or writes are not-atomic (x86 for unaligned data) how can thread2 on Core2 possibly request Core1 (busy with thread1) to properly release the data / complete writes / etc? As far as I know, there are no such commands!

What I am missing here?

**EDIT.** Please note, suggested duplicate doesn't answer my question. It reiterates my statement, but doesn't explain how the effect can possibly be achieved. In particular, it doesn't explain how Core2 can put memory barrier on data inside Core1's cache.

Comment: I share your confusion. Looks like a potential race condition to me. Which part of your reading shows how this is safe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a full memory barrier around sem\_post(sem\_t \* sem) and sem\_wait(sem\_t \* sem)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431679/is-there-a-full-memory-barrier-around-sem-postsem-t-sem-and-sem-waitsem-t)

Comment: Read this:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11, where it states **The following functions synchronize memory with respect to other threads**

Comment: @flatmouse, everywhere? *man sem_overview* for instance.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, neither of your links answers my question, it just reiterates what I've said. I am asking **how**.

Comment: If sem_post/sem_wait does not provide fencing then explicit fencing/memory barrier instruction is required. Are looking for specific instructions on memory fencing?

Comment: @SergeyA *neither of your links answers my question, it just reiterates what I've said. I am asking how.*  It took me about 30 seconds to find the question this is a duplicate of.  And no, you did not ask *how*, you asked *why*:  This question is titled *Why any thread can unlock a semaphore?*  *Why* is because `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` synchronize memory per the POSIX standard I linked to.  You also asked *What I am missing here?*  You missed the fact that POSIX requires memory synchronization from `sem_post()` and `sem_wait()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I missed nothing. But you seem to be missing the whole last paragraph of my question (before the edit) and haven't read past the title 'why'.

Comment: @SergeyA Ok, fair enough. Commonly known. I still have to start with `man man`. :)

Comment: @SergeyA *I missed nothing*?  Oh?  *how can thread2 on Core2 possibly request Core1 (busy with thread1) to properly release the data / complete writes / etc? As far as I know, there are no such commands!*  [Yes, there are.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)  Here's one for x86:  http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_170.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle, nothing in this link says that mfence can be used to perform release operation on another CPU. It also is for x86, which has strong memory ordering built into it, so it's rather moot. ARM spec would be more relevant.

Comment: Downvoted.  This is getting tedious.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, downvoting for not knowing the answer? This is something new.

Comment: @SergeyA You didn't even bother to read the MFENCE link I provided, did you?  Did you see the part where it states:  **It should be noted that processors are...**.  Note the use of the word processors.  As in plural - more than one.  I found links that actually document answers to your questions in just a few minutes.  I downvoted you because you deserve it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, no, it says, that CPUs are allowed to prefetch. It's plural because of grammar. And you don't seem to understand what I am talking about at all. You miss the fact that x86 is strong memory ordering chip, so there is no sequencing issue for x86. You did downvote, and you do not seem to have even slightest idea of what I am talking about, so please move on to the next question.

Comment: @SergeyA  Google "cache coherence" and quit expecting everyone to solve your problems for you.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I am well aware of cache coherence. But you do not understand what weak memory ordering is, right? I googled something for you (hoping that  you will make yourself busy with reading it and will move away from my obnoxious question): https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/cache-coherency/

Comment: @SergeyA You mean like the PowerPC `sync` instruction?  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.aixassem/doc/alangref/sync.htm%23a28692bf  Multiprocessor machines have solved this problem.  I can find the solutions.

Comment: @SergeyA, your C example code is a tremendous distraction to what you seem actually to be asking.  Indeed, if, as it now seems, your question is fundamentally about CPU instruction sets, then the question is poorly tagged.  In that case, simplify your example to one semaphore, choose at most one of C or C++, and retag the question with something more likely to attract assembly programmers or experts in the CPU instruction set that interests you.  At this point, and given how different that question would be, you might just delete this one and post a new one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I need two semaphores because I need to signal the other guy to post to the main one. And I used language tags because I am using the C/C++ language to illustrate the question (I am not familiar with ASM to illustrate the question in ASM).

Comment: @SergeyA, if you're not prepared to appreciate an answer in terms of CPU instructions, and you reject answers that simply point to the specifications that say it works, then I have no idea what kind of answer you're actually looking for.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I am ready to appreciate it, I can read ASM quite well. I am not ready to write ASM for point of illustrating my question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it does this by waiting for signals (controlled by the OS) from the POSIX Threads Library for Win32:

```
       * If the sema is posted between us being cancelled and us locking
       * the sema again above then we need to consume that post but cancel
       * anyway. If we don't get the semaphore we indicate that we're no
       * longer waiting.
       */
      if (*((sem_t *)sem) != NULL && !(WaitForSingleObject(s->sem, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0))
    {
      ++s->value;
#if defined(NEED_SEM)
      if (s->value > 0)
        {
          s->leftToUnblock = 0;
        }
#else
      /*
       * Don't release the W32 sema, it doesn't need adjustment
       * because it doesn't record the number of waiters.
       */
#endif /* NEED_SEM */
    }
      (void) pthread_mutex_unlock (&s->lock);
    }
}
```

Of course we don't have the Windows source code at our disposal. So the trail for the POSIX implementation ends there.

This is not the case for Linux. `sem_wait.c` makes use of `futex_wait()`, and it is in the source for this function that a determination is made as to whether or not the CPU can support certain functions. For example; does the CPU have a compare and exchange function? But even there the full capabilities of the architecture isn't fully considered. Functions such as `lll_futex_wait()` are defined in `lowlevellock.h`. So for PowerPC we have `powerpc/lowlevellock.h`, with the following snippet for example:

```
/* Set *futex to ID if it is 0, atomically.  Returns the old value */
#define __lll_robust_trylock(futex, id) \
  ({ int __val;                                   \
     __asm __volatile ("1:  lwarx   %0,0,%2" MUTEX_HINT_ACQ "\n"          \
               "    cmpwi   0,%0,0\n"                 \
               "    bne 2f\n"                     \
               "    stwcx.  %3,0,%2\n"                \
               "    bne-    1b\n"                     \
               "2:  " __lll_acq_instr                 \
               : "=&r" (__val), "=m" (*futex)                 \
               : "r" (futex), "r" (id), "m" (*futex)              \
               : "cr0", "memory");                    \
     __val;                                   \
  })
```

So the answer is probably that if it was implemented on Linux then there is probably some implementation or workaround in the architecture specific library that works around 'missing' instructions.

Comment: Not sure how this code is relevant. All I see it windows-specific WaitForSingleObject and pthread_mutex_unlock, which can't be happening from non-owning thread.

Comment: Correct, this is from the POSIX Threads Library for Win32. In Linux the `sem_wait` function would be implemented differently but provide the same functionality. The question asked about POSIX, the OS wasn't specified.

Comment: Indeed,.  The actual semaphore implementation is necessarily OS and architecture-specific.  POSIX lives on top of that.

Answer (score -1):

Let if initial value of sem1 = 1 and sem2 = 0 then thread 3 and thread 1 both can take lock. It depends on which thread enters first..Suppose if thread 3 execute first then sem1 will become 0 now and thread 1 can not take the lock and also thread 2 can not take the lock because of its dependency on thread 1. And if initial value of sem1 = 0 then no thread can get lock....I think this will help..

Comment: This is not the answer at all, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

...because that is how it is defined.

Any thread may post a unit to a semaphore.

A semaphore is not primarily a locking mechanism, so 'unlock' is inappropriate.

Semaphores support post and wait.

In the case of complex architectures, eg. many multi-core processors, implementation of semaphore, and other inter-thread synchro mechanisms may get quite complex.  It might, for example, be necessary to send a synchro message via the inter-processor driver, so hardware-interrupting the other cores/s to force them to handle the synchro.

Comment: Still not an answer. I have very specific question on how exactly this is achieved.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on improving the title? I am not very happy with it myself, but I can't come up with a better one.

Comment: Well, now we are getting somewhere. My problem is that I was not able to find any indication that this 'synchro message via the inter-processor driver' exists.

Comment: How about 'How can semaphores implemented on multi-core systems?

Comment: @SergeyA - how else do you think that comms is achieved across multiple cores?  When a process terminates, for example, all its threads must be stopped before other resources, like memory, can be freed off.  If a process thread is running on another core than the one requesting the termination, it has to be stopped, and so the other core must be hardware-interrupted.  That means an inter-core driver.

Comment: This question probably belongs on the 'operating systems' tag, since semaphores are OS-supported synchro primitives.

Comment: Process termination is a release operation on it's own. Control is switched to OS, and at this point everything happens, full memory barierrs and whatever else is needed. By my endless loop doesn't switch, and doesn't have any memory barriers in it.

Comment: When it wants to stop a thread, the OS does not care about endless loops, barriers, whatever.  It forces the core running it to enter the OS with a hardware interrupt.  It needs no barriers, atomics, whatever.  The thread is gonna die, no matter what it tries to do to escape.

Comment: Martin, absolutely. And there is no guarantee whatsoever that modifications done by this thread are persisted.