# Preventing gcc from FP optimizations spanning over an inline assembly instruction that might change FP math

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, compiler-optimization, riscv

I am doing some research on RISC-V processors, i have created csr register that changes how the processor does float calculations. Is there any way to create a boundary, so that gcc will perform optimizations before and after i write to the csr, but no optimizations spanning over the csr write.

Example:

```
#define write_csr(reg, val)({\
  asm volatile ("csrw " #reg ", %0" :: "rK"(val)); })

float a = 0.0f;
float b = 0.0f; 
float z = a/b; 

write_csr(some_csr) // <--- Everthing before and after this should be treated seperatly for optimizations.

float new_z = a/b;
```

When i compile and run this with `-O2` optimization level gcc performs common subexpression elimination so that `new_z` wont be recomputed (only one fdiv.s instruction is issued). For this example i can solve the problem by using `volatile float b` instead of `float b`, however i want to insert this `write_csr` funtion into more complex programs, without having to worry about optimizations.

Comment: Do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943540/why-can-asm-volatile-memory-serve-as-a-compiler-barrier answer your question?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: I don't think the `memory` clobber helps here because `a,b` are not in memory (their address has not been taken).

Comment: Does `-frounding-math` help?  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath - apparently no, "*GCC currently assumes that the same rounding mode is in effect everywhere*" according to the wiki, which links https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34678.  So GCC doesn't fully support something equivalent to `#pragma STDC FENV ACCESS ON`.  Perhaps if the CSR write was in an opaque non-inline function call, like `__attribute__((noinline,noipa))`, that might help GCC, since `-ftrapping-math` is on by default so it might have to assume that FP exception flags have been reset.

Comment: But generally `-ftrapping-math` is buggy and sometimes allows optimizations which change the number of FP exceptions from zero to non-zero or vice-versa, and blocks some optimizations that don't do that.  It's on by default, which is unfortunate in many cases (*[Why gcc is so much worse at std::vector vectorization of a conditional multiply than clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76683811)*)

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, sadly I was not able to resolve this yet. 
I will post an update if I find anything else on Monday.