# In C++, will a copy of mutex protected data be optimized away?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, compiler-optimization

In C++, will a copy of mutex-protected data be optimized away?

I'd like to make a snapshot of the protected data, and read thru it outside of the mutex. Would this copy get optimized away though, leaving me either reading the original protected data inside the mutex (bad for performance), or worse, reading the original protected data outside of the mutex (unsafe)?

I'm most interested in using the built-in C++ mutexes.

**Thread 1**

```
while (1)
{
  my_mutex.lock();
  data = ... /* Modifications to the data. */
  my_mutex.unlock();
  
  ... /* Unrelated stuff. */
}
```

**Thread 2**

```
while (1)
{
  my_mutex.lock();
  snapshot = data; /* Take a snapshot of the protected data. */
  my_mutex.unlock();
  
  ... /* Read various things in the snapshot. */
}
```

Comment: Note try not to lock/unlock manually. Use `std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock{my_mutex};` and trust the destructor of std::scoped_lock to unlock for you (RAII). Then even when an exception occurs or your function has multiple return paths your mutex will always be unlockded. Also I hope your threads have a way to break the while loop if needed, you should not have to kill them at shutdown.

Comment: And no with the code you show the mutex will not be optimizad away.

Comment: As long as `snapshot` is in scope it will exist.   As long as `snapshot` is a deep copy of `data` rather than a shallow copy (i.e. doesn't contain pointers to a member of `data`) it can be used when the mutex is unlocked.

Comment: Classic example of, "If this doesn't work, I have a <expletive deleted>load of code to fix."

Comment: Is this question purely theoretical? What problem are you trying to solve? Do you see it not working in your case? Could you share more details of how you debug? What have you tried?

Comment: You have to lock, And wrap data with its protection. You can optimize data if its possible to divide it to parts where each part has its protection.

Comment: Compilers don't just break legal code because they feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

> reading the original protected data outside of the mutex (unsafe)?

That definitely can't happen.  [How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951011/how-does-a-mutex-lock-and-unlock-functions-prevents-cpu-reordering/50951199#50951199) explains how implementations prevent correctness problems from both compile-time and run-time reordering.

If a compiler has a `std::mutex` that it can see through all the way to a `lock_var.store(0, std::memory_order_release)`, then `release` tells the compiler that it might sync-with another thread, so loads/stores before that store need to stay before that store. (The as-if rule would let it reorder stores to local vars that no other thread could have a reference to anyway, but not accesses to possibly-shared data like your `data`.)

Or if the implementation uses `asm("" :::"memory")` or equivalent, then it's a full compiler barrier.

If neither of those, it'd be obviously broken, and problems would have happened.

---

> reading the original protected data inside the mutex (bad for performance)

You're worried about the compiler moving later computations *into* the critical section, making it hold the lock for longer?

That's unlikely in practice (and in some cases limited or impossible even in theory) since `my_mutex.unlock();` will normally involve a non-inline function (like `pthread_mutex_unlock()`) that's fully opaque to the optimizer (and has to be assumed to read/write any globally reachable object: [How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951011/how-does-a-mutex-lock-and-unlock-functions-prevents-cpu-reordering)).

So any modification of globals or pointed-to memory (anything that the compiler can't prove is a local var) will be done after that `unlock` function call.

We can construct some cases where some computation did happen while holding the lock, but probably only small amounts that only involves registers, so not actually a performance problem.  Especially since out-of-order exec can probably overlap the computation with the unlock anyway.

e.g. summing 8-bit elements of a small array (in a struct or not), vs. copying the array to a local temporary and looping after.

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

void lock(void *);  // just some non-inline functions the compiler knows nothing about
void unlock(void*);
int mylock;

static const int bufsize = 23; // 16
struct buf { uint8_t buf[bufsize]; } shared;

// just copy inside the critical section in the source
int foo(){
    lock(&mylock);
    buf tmp = shared;
    unlock(&mylock);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(tmp.buf)/sizeof(tmp.buf[0]) ; i++){
        sum += tmp.buf[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

// and a bar() with the work inside the critical section in the source
```

In the cases [I looked at on x86-64 and ARM (**Godbolt**)](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzGakAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmscHI3lgA1CaxboP4ggB0CHvYJhoAgpdXAG6oeOjbtKjIANYQD0/bAFQzews222AHoQdttF5BtsFKg2NsGAIALTBWjBTDbKheBgOdIKbYEBAYtAsRJ0aLbd6IgDu%2BMRhOCwG2TAiCwIt2%2Bz2xrw%2BX0e6H%2BgNuwQI2xYAE8ee8hddbuNHMhtmgGNCRdsIl4qKkAF4YvYAEW2ZligNB4K4ADY5QRiF4HOrNbsAOxArwigAcAH1RRqqCYAKwWX06zAB/WmkxOw0KBD1TDoGU3a5giFQ0VoRLi7bBVI7QnE4hpUS0GGYXECbMMAlEmELJah65q/ioCAAl23YHAqUQcwWiVSgGxKzXTsOqgE0m7WLR2PEeOJ0fct6fXv95eD4dXUdqhQ%2BKeGjQLzv8YjbCBqvD77YaKdAy97NwwvC61BUCAEUnHX0zEEh1/vz9fQDCxD39fUZlvbNrGsNtN1HUddxYXZLANCdEi/TVgLwMMj2BSNwxHTs5wIRYq0QxN8NuW4U2pEh3krXMMXzJVCwVMRS3LKtgmrDFYUWZZhUEdV6lbSM4M7btV0lddcMrUVEKvQ8hw7Y8SDPC9FMg%2B99ifF83xjON0Awqgfz/fTZ3jYzgNA8CtOgyxYJU%2BCYT3aDpxhCyjKAwNsLA2TKMI4El15KSB1k4jSJclgKKjW4ODmWhOH9Xg/A4LRSFQTg3HsoE%2BPrZDYh4UgCE0eK5neEAzAtY4zH9DR3S4MwzC4f0nTMSRJAATmkRKOEkFLSoyzheAUEANGK0q5jgWAkBJMl6DICgIDm8kYnqFhgC4eJxqwO48GWAA1PBMGpAB5RJGE4IqaFoAholGiAIkGiJgnqcUrt4F7mGIcVToibQyxK7heBJNhBFOhhaHetLeCwDVgDcMRaFG4HSCwFhDGAcQYbRvA51xO5MBR9LMFUMsvDuj7yEESpBrRCJiDejwsCpm08BYD65ioAxgAUI6TvOy7Uf4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQcd0VoDCMFAcv0PAIlGyA5lQRJqhRpFTtibYkRYZBEi8A00AaUmkSYf0jaRKhESRMlMF4VBCeIQssE11s2kB9IXAYdxPGafxg8mPoYlaXI0gEEYWiSFI44YSOSn6MZKgDgROmGUPRn9zjc%2B6dEpgz2whkafPE/GBo0%2BmLg5jy5ZZn0JKBpxzKOG2K4ACUAFltgAcTcR8tpq44bwgXBCDUtZG94IGtBmcrKtiY4nS6rh3SdJ13UkMwnX9OqLTbvreA5rgNHG1L0q7kaxommGppgRAUDhebonISgVoWkBNvKLtfamB%2BZnQuqla6dA7rEAek9HGX03pUwQT9P6AMHBU1BowAgEMoaDThl4BGSMUZFXRpjbG6V8D40cITYmvBSbk0pqjEUtMcb00Zj9ZmKwipsw5sDLmPM%2BbHTAULa6sgxbiEliLeQSg1CDV0AkJWxhVb019trXWeJOAGwdhjJYZxpwKHeJKJg7w3YZU9t7Im8Am5Z04kHEOWRE6BFLlHHIydqgJ1cXkdI9dy52GzjUSuHjM7tBzpXHx0cK5dCCZEuuzj07RybnWFujcz7JVILfd2nBtiqHdBaJEFpJDbGAMgRU48zBnhnkQU888ZiL0mqvdqxxOrNJaa01pp9er9XSYNe%2BthH5L3iqQaab9f5fyWqMmImxMZcCdBoVoQDDpCMFhA3gN1oGwOeq9H6SCtm/X%2BoDDBcIwbYMhtDChmB4aI1oMjKmpCjDkNhnjAONDBr0OQBTLhvBmG9XSmwpmGBPnFULLwng/CmC81AcsqmUjxES2kFImWsj5ZxH0JjFWKFLBqw1lYjK6iBD60NsCR2ztXbu3MU8SxWtC7VDsdEpxRQXGxH9EnLx8dq6eJTuEuIzK/FF0Cey4J/ji5csKjEquDiBhhLidMQqiT%2BISwSu3bpncsk5LyQUpUijtgzMnscLgFT8BVIKgvJ%2By8GnMs6R3O%2Bw0%2BnjQGSvM%2BZgrWZI4HU5%2BcxPapGcJIIAA), GCC does just copy, sometimes with partially-overlapping stores for odd sizes.  (Which it does in an unfortunate order, creating a store-forwarding stall on relead if `unlock` is cheap (just a release-store, not an RMW) enough that they're still in the store buffer.  But that's a separate problem, and outside the critical section.)

I picked this as a possible worst case: not a huge amount of data to copy, but processing each byte separately so we get the most work per byte.  But it is still just adding, not storing to another data structure, and can be sped up with SIMD.  (Clang is good at that for some sizes, using `psadbw` against a zeroed vector to sum unsigned bytes in 64-bit chunks.  But for larger sizes forgets that trick :/  Also, odd sizes partly defeat it.)

GCC13 `-O3 -march=skylake` for x86-64 starts out with purely copying, not doing any work.

```
# GCC13.2 -O3 -march=skylake
foo():
        sub     rsp, 40

        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:mylock
        call    lock(void*)
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR shared[rip+15]
        vmovdqa xmm3, XMMWORD PTR shared[rip]
          mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:mylock     # arg for unlock
        vmovdqa XMMWORD PTR [rsp], xmm3       # 16-byte store
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+15], rax       # 8-byte store overlaps by 1 byte
        call    unlock(void*)
    # end of critical section
        vmovdqa xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp]    # reload
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rsp+16]     # other bytes are loaded with scalar as well

        vpmovzxbw       xmm1, xmm0
        vpsrldq xmm0, xmm0, 8
        vpmovzxwd       xmm2, xmm1
         ... # a really inefficient horizontal-sum pattern that takes multiple shuffles to widen chunks,
             # worse than if it used  vpunpcklbw / vpunpckhbw against a zeroed vector
             # even if they miss the psadbw trick for unsigned bytes specifically
             # code gen with just SSE2, without -march=skylake, takes more xor-zeroing but fewer shuffles, probably less bad.

        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vmovd   eax, xmm0
        add     eax, edx
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rsp+17]
        add     edx, eax
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsp+18]
        add     eax, edx
        ...
```

So yeah, GCC does a lot of total work, but just copying inside the critical section.

**Clang on the other hand does put some work into the critical section, but barely more than what copying would already take.**  (As a global variable, compilers know that `shared` is aligned by 16; it's bigger than 16 bytes so the x86-64 SysV ABI actually guarantees that, and the compiler could over-align if it wanted.)

```
# clang 17.0.1 -O3
foo():
        push    rbp
        push    rbx               # save two call-preserved regs
        sub     rsp, 40           # and reserve scratch space + align the stack for a call

        mov     edi, offset mylock
        call    lock(void*)
## Start of critical section
        movzx   ebx, byte ptr [rip + shared+20]   # multiple separate byte loads, zero-extending
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rip + shared+21]
        movzx   ebp, byte ptr [rip + shared+22]   # some into call-preserved regs
        add     ebp, eax                          # consume the byte load into a call-clobbered reg
        movdqa  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + shared+16]
        movdqa  xmmword ptr [rsp + 16], xmm0    # 16-byte Spill
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        movdqa  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rip + shared]
        psadbw  xmm1, xmm0                         ## one step now of the vector work
        movdqa  xmmword ptr [rsp], xmm1         # 16-byte Spill
        mov     edi, offset mylock
        call    unlock(void*)
## end of critical section

        movdqa  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rsp]         # 16-byte Reload (of the PSADBW result)
        pshufd  xmm0, xmm1, 238                 # xmm0 = xmm1[2,3,2,3]
        paddq   xmm0, xmm1                        # shuffle and hsum it
        movd    ecx, xmm0
        movdqa  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsp + 16]    # 16-byte Reload
        pxor    xmm1, xmm1
        punpckldq       xmm0, xmm1              # xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[0],xmm0[1],xmm1[1]
        psadbw  xmm0, xmm1                      # hsum of bytes [16..19] into the low qword of xmm0
        movd    eax, xmm0                       # extract the low dword, ignoring the hsum of garbage in the high qword
        add     eax, ebx
        add     eax, ecx
        add     eax, ebp
        add     rsp, 40
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Silly compiler; vector reload + `pshufd` + `paddq` + `movd` hsum of the first 16 bytes could have just been `mov eax, [rsp]` / `add eax, [rsp+8]`.  Since it had to spill/reload anyway, it could have taken advantage of the fact to get it directly into integer regs while reloading.

In `bar()`, with the work inside the critical section, that does make sense because nothing forced a spill/reload.

Notice that clang copies 32 bytes; it knows it's aligned by 16, and that there are some valid bytes in high 16-byte chunk it's loading, so this is guaranteed not to cross a page or cache-line boundary and can't fault.  (*[Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64)*)  It only needed to copy 8, and could have done it with an integer register like GCC did.

With size=16, clang does `pxor xmm0, xmm0` / `psadbw xmm0, [rip+shared]`, using a memory source for the ALU instruction.  (Which is allowed even for legacy-SSE since we know it's aligned.)

For this odd size, clang could have done a better job by doing all 7 "leftover" bytes with a right-shift (by 1 byte) to discard 1 byte of garbage to feed another hsum.  Like `movq xmm1, qword ptr [rip + shared]` + `psllq xmm1, 8` (bit-shift by 8 discards the top byte from the low qword) / `psadbw xmm1, xmm0`.

e.g. I think a good tradeoff would be to do 16-byte and 8-byte vector loads inside the critical section, and maybe vector store of the 16-byte psadbw result, but `movd ebx, xmm1` of the psadbw result from the high 7 bytes.  That's only a handful of uops without high latency so they can retire quickly and let the unlock commit and become globally visible.  Then after unlock, `add ebx, [rsp]` / `mov eax, [rsp+8]` / `add eax, ebx` / restore RSP and `pop rbx` / `ret`.  (Or even use `pop rax` and maybe `pop rcx` to reload and restore the stack instead of `add rsp, 16` or `8`, if we've arranged to only need 16 or even 8 bytes of scratch space by doing more hsum work before storing.)

---

##### TL:DR: Yes, some small amount of work can move into the critical section, but it's pretty negligible.  I didn't see a case where compilers moved a huge amount of work in.  Hopefully their heuristics actively try not to reorder large amounts of work with unknown function calls.

For a fully-inlinable `unique_lock` on `std::mutex`, yes it's more possible, but as a quality-of-implementation issue compilers *shouldn't* move atomic stores past long-running loops, and I think don't.  My guess is that the worst-case amount of work is similar to how much a compiler would be willing to unroll a loop.

Re: compilers optimizing atomics including past slow loops, see

- [N4455 No Sane Compiler Would Optimize Atomics](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4455.html)
- [P0062R1: When should compilers optimize atomics?](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0062r1.html)
- [Why don't compilers merge redundant std::atomic writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960387/why-dont-compilers-merge-redundant-stdatomic-writes)

Comment: What if we use LTO, so that code in another translation unit is not opaque to the compiler anymore?  It seems like another barrier to optimization is needed in this case.

Comment: @TrentP: On Linux/glibc, `pthread_mutex_unlock` is in a separately-compiled shared library so it can't get inlined even with LTO.  I suspect most platforms are like this, but now that I think about it, I don't know about MSVC on Windows.

Comment: I was under the impression that code like this, [pthead_mutex_unlock.c:161](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_mutex_unlock.c;h=d182b9339597018eb3c4cc2b139891604398f694;hb=HEAD#l161) in `pthread_mutex_unlock()`'s implementation was needed to provide a compiler optimization barrier.

Comment: @TrentP: If you did make an LTO static library version of `libpthread.a`, then yes, that `asm("" ::: "memory")` compiler barrier would come into play.  If not, as I explained in [How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951199), any opaque function call is exactly as strong (in GCC at least), probably with the same compiler internals tracking what can reorder past it.  (e.g. escape analysis to find any local vars that nothing else could have a pointer to, and thus don't need to have an address).  That's why I linked it in this answer.

Comment: It's interesting to see that some work can be moved into the critical section.

Comment: If we replace the `unlock()` call in your examples with `asm("":::"memory")`, I think it's not exactly as strong, as the function call clobbers caller-saved registers, while the asm does not.  Clang at least is able to load `shared` in registers inside the lock and avoids ever copying it to `buf` (which is never allocated on the stack).  I think the reason it didn't do that before was the unlock could clobber the registers.

Comment: @TrentP: True, that's a good point about register clobbers affecting where it does work. That makes it easier for the compiler to just load everything and do work later, without tradeoffs other than maybe doing the first step of something with a memory-source ALU instruction on CISC ISAs like x86-64.

Answer (score 0):

Lock and unlock operations on a mutex act as memory barriers.  No read or write of any object can be reordered before the lock, or after the unlock.  So the code is safe.

(An exception would be for an object with local scope whose address has not been passed outside the function, such that no other thread could possibly be accessing it concurrently.)

Technically, the copy *could* be optimized out, if for instance you never read the value you stored into `snapshot`.  The compiler cannot move the read of `data` outside the critical section, but it can skip the read altogether if it can prove it is unnecessary.

It is also allowed for the compiler to make multiple reads from `data` inside the critical section; this cannot introduce a data race unless there was one already.  So, for instance, if you read from `snapshot` before unlocking the mutex, the compiler could in principle generate a second read from `data` instead.  Hopefully a good compiler would only do this in cases where it was *good* for performance (e.g. if no register was available to cache the value), but either way, it's conformant.  The C++ standard generally doesn't mandate performance, so  if your compiler generates sub-optimal code, you have to take it up with the compiler vendor directly.

Comment: I think the OP is worried about moving later computations *into* the critical section, making it hold the lock for longer.  That's unlikely in practice since `my_mutex.unlock();` will normally involve a non-inline function that's fully opaque to the optimizer (and has to be assumed to read/write any globally reachable object: [How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50951011)).  So any modification of globals or pointed-to memory that the compiler can't prove is a local var will be done after that function call.

Comment: @Peter. I'm most interested in the built-in C++ mutexes right now. I'm assuming their implementation may not be opaque to the optimizer, so I'm kind of curious how that would change things.

Comment: I'm still curious if the compiler *could* decide to eliminate the `snapshot` copy, as it may see no reason to keep a copy that remains the same as the original. Does C++, which is now multithreading, “know” that `data` could be changed elsewhere? Or perhaps, does it “know” that I was trying to protected it?

Comment: @uncreate: If a compiler has a `std::mutex` that it can see through all the way to a `lock_var.store(0, std::memory_order_release)`, then `release` tells the compiler that it might sync-with another thread, so loads/stores before that store need to stay before that store.  (The as-if rule would let it reorder stores to local vars that no other thread could have a reference to anyway, but not accesses to possibly-shared data like `data`.)  Or if the implementation uses `asm("" :::"memory")` or equivalent, then it's a full compiler barrier.  If neither of those, it'd be obviously broken.