# Relation of Mutex and CPU caches (and memory fences)

Tags: caching, mutex, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-barriers

Suppose I have an application with *multiple* threads that need to access some *shared* data.

I know that a **mutex** (Critical Section) can be used to ensure that *at most* one thread at a time can access the shared data. This prevents the case that one thread reads the shared data while another thread is currently modifying the shared data, which otherwise could lead to reading an inconsistent state. The mutex also prevents the case that multiple threads are modifying the shared data at the same time, which otherwise could lead to conflicting writes.

Now, on the machine with multiple processors or multiple CPU cores, there is another problem: If a thread `A` running on processor #1 modifies the shared data, and then thread `B` running on processor #2 reads the shared data, thread `B` may still "see" some *outdated* data – even if mutual exclusion was enforced. That is because, in general, each processor (core) has its own local CPU cache. So, unless the caches are flushed, even after the shared data was modified in main memory (RAM) from one CPU, the other CPUs can still have an "old" version in their local caches!

To my understanding, a *mutex* ***alone*** does not fix this caching issue, because a mutex is all about enforcing a specific ordering of the accesses, but, in general, a mutex does *nothing* regarding the CPU caches. After all, there is **not** even a way to "bind" a mutex to certain memory addresses that would need to be flushed from the CPU caches when the mutex is acquired or released.

So, how do we deal with this "cache synchronization" problem in practice?

And how exactly do **memory fences** fit into the picture? I know they exist to prevent re-ordering of memory access, but, again, it is **not** clear how this effects multiple CPUs. Do I need to combine a *mutex* with a *memory fence* to prevent a thread from reading *outdated* data from local cache?

---

I have read mutex documentation (e.g. `Enter/LeaveCriticalSection()`), but it does **not** clarify how the mutex functions will interact with the processor caches...

Also, I have read that one can allocate memory pages, e.g. via `VirtualAlloc()` function, with the special **PAGE_NOCACHE** flag, so that those pages will *not* be cached at all. But is this really necessary, whenever data needs to be shared across processor cores ???

Comment: The hardware works through memory barriers for cache coherency and a mutex is a software abstraction built upon them. It is common to combine them, like a load-load barrier to read immutable data (lock-free) and a mutex to serialize the mutex writes (copy-on-write); e.g. a concurrent hash table. The resources that I found useful were the Herb Sutter's "Atomic Weapons" talk, The Art of Microprocessor Programming, "On The Fence With Dependencies", "Close Encounters of The Java Memory Model Kind", Doug Lea's "Using JDK 9 Memory Order Modes", and kernel.org's "Linux Kernel Memory Barriers".

Comment: @BenManes: CPU cache is coherent whether you use barriers or not.  Barrier instructions block local reordering of accesses to coherent cache, but loads will still see stores from other cores with `memory_order_relaxed` (which compiles to just a plain load or store).  https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/ / https://software.rajivprab.com/2018/04/29/myths-programmers-believe-about-cpu-caches/ .  This is why atomic release and acquire operations are fairly cheap, and we don't need to tell our CPUs which cache lines are shared for locking to work.

Comment: Related: [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535118) explains some of the implications of CPUs having coherent cache between cores that multiple threads can use.

Comment: Maybe related: [How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50951011).  But I don't think the answers there address the question of why / how memory barrier instructions work, and neither mention that caches are coherent.

Comment: Related for one specific architecture: [C++ How is release-and-acquire achieved on x86 only using MOV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60314179).  That's mostly about why x86 doesn't even need barrier instructions where others do (because of strong memory-ordering rules in x86), but part of the reason is that barriers don't flush cache on other ISAs either, the just order access to coherent cache.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh yes, thank you for correcting my poor wording and being more exact. I tend to think in terms of weak memory models where I want to be explicit about the memory ordering and visibility so that store buffering, etc. don't surprise me. Otherwise I think it is easy to confuse cache coherency with a thread's visibility and make bad assumptions.

Comment: @BenManes: Yeah, ordering and visibility are very separate things.  Once you know cache is coherent (and that's the mechanism for visibility), you know visibility happens on its own even in CPUs with memory-ordering rules as weak as ISO C++'s memory model.  And that [barriers make basically no difference to how quickly anything becomes visible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61591287), just the order, because the store buffer already tries to drain itself as quickly as possible, and OoO exec of loads is limited to a short window (few hundred insns).

Comment: Thanks for the links. But it's still **not** really clear how it all comes together. Suppose I'm programming in C, **not** assembler language (or machine code), and I use a ***mutex***, e.g. `CRITICAL_SECTION` on Windows or `pthread_mutex_t` on Linux, to protect/serialize the access to the shared data, what exactly do I need to do *additionally* in order to ensure ***cache coherence***? Is it safe to assume that the mutex implementation "automatically" inserts the required memory fences to ensure cache coherence? Or do I need to call function like `MemoryBarrier()` explicitly?

Comment: @WilliamCole:  Didn't see your response since you didn't @ notify me.  `pthread_mutex_lock()` / `unlock` or C11 `mtx_lock` or whatever are responsible for using acquire and release operations when taking/releasing the lock to control the visibility-order of stuff in the critical section so it stays between the lock/unlock.  Hardware maintains cache coherence on its own so ordering local accesses to L1d cache is sufficient for mutex functions.  On a hypothetical machine without hardware cache coherence, `lock`/`unlock`, they'd probably have to flush caches.

Comment: In no case do you have to call `MemoryBarrier()` or `atomic_thread_fence(release)` or `_mm_mfence()` yourself, as long as you're just using standard mutex functions correctly, not lock-free atomics.

Comment: Better late than never. Thanks, it's good to know that "standard" mutex implementations can be assumed to take care of memory ordering and cache coherency – as far as this is necessary on the hardware platform. I think the documentation of `CRITICAL_SECTION`, `pthread_mutex_t` and similar implementations should point this out more clearly! Also, I think you should turn your comment into an actual answer in order to get the bounty ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pthread_mutex_lock()` / unlock or C11 `mtx_lock` or whatever are responsible for using [acquire and release operations](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) when taking/releasing the lock to control the visibility-order of stuff in the critical section so it stays between the lock/unlock. Hardware maintains cache coherence on its own so ordering local accesses to L1d cache is sufficient for mutex functions.

(Yes, [this is true for all CPUs we run threads across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118).  If you have CPUs that share memory but without cache coherence, you don't run threads of the same program across those cores, like a DSP and a microcontroller.)

On a hypothetical machine without hardware cache coherence, `lock`/`unlock` would probably have to manually fully flush caches.  (Since the mutex API doesn't doesn't provide it with address ranges for shared data.)

In no case do you have to call `MemoryBarrier()` or `atomic_thread_fence(release)` or `_mm_mfence()` yourself, as long as you're just using standard mutex functions correctly, not lock-free atomics.

If you look at C++'s `std::mutex` operations, or the C11 equivalent, they are formally documented as being release and acquire operations which makes it 100% clear they work between threads to create a happens-before relationship.  (This usage for mutexes is where the names `release` and `acquire` for lock-free operations and memory barriers came from.  See [Jeff Preshing's excellent article](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) which I also linked earlier)

If you look at the POSIX docs, they also talk about "release" and "acquire" of mutexes.  Almost certainly there's a formal definition somewhere of those terms in a way that guarantees they work between threads even if those threads are running concurrently on an SMP machine.  If you don't realize the significance of "release" and "acquire" as technical terms, perhaps you missed it.

---

Somewhat related: *[How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951011/how-does-a-mutex-lock-and-unlock-functions-prevents-cpu-reordering)* also covers compile-time reordering by being a non-inline function.  (Or if it was fully defined in headers with atomic ops, then those atomic ops would limit reordering sufficiently.)

Comment: The [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html) isn't as formal here as one might wish.  There's just 4.12 with the vague statement that these functions "synchronize memory", a phrase which is not defined precisely anywhere else.  They unfortunately never harmonized the POSIX spec with the C11 memory model, it seems.  Still, it's surely safe to assume in practice that the `posix_*` mutex operations have the same memory ordering semantics as `std::mutex`.

Answer (score -3):

In an environment with multiple cores or processors. It is extremely important to ensure synchronization and prevent any issues with data inconsistency caused by CPU caches when programming concurrently. Lets now delve into your questions and address them one, by one;

**Cache Synchronization and Mutex:**

Indeed, a mutex alone does not automatically handle cache synchronization. When a thread acquires a mutex and modifies shared data, there's no guarantee that the changes made to the shared data are immediately visible to other threads running on different processors.

**Memory Fences:**

Memory fences (also known as memory barriers) come into play to control the order of memory operations and provide a means to synchronize caches between processors. Memory fences ensure that certain memory operations are completed before others. They prevent the compiler and CPU from reordering memory operations, which is crucial for maintaining the desired sequence of operations.

In the context of multithreading, you might use memory fences to ensure that certain memory operations (read or write) are completed before or after other memory operations. For example, in C++, you might use functions like std::atomic_thread_fence or platform-specific instructions to create memory fences.

**Mutex and Memory Fences Combination:**

Combining a mutex with appropriate memory fences is a common practice to address cache synchronization issues. When you acquire a mutex, it often implies acquiring a lock and should come with the necessary memory synchronization. Modern mutex implementations generally include memory barriers to ensure that memory operations are visible across different CPU cores.

**Memory Pages with PAGE_NOCACHE:**

Allocating memory pages with the PAGE_NOCACHE flag can indeed be used to avoid caching issues. However, this approach is more aggressive and might result in performance penalties, as it forces the system to fetch data directly from RAM every time, bypassing the CPU caches. It is often used when fine-grained control over cache behavior is required, but it might not be necessary in every case.

**Practical Approach:**

In practice, relying on well-designed mutex implementations provided by the operating system or threading libraries often takes care of the necessary cache synchronization. Combining mutexes with memory fences is a robust approach to ensure proper synchronization and ordering of memory operations across multiple threads and processors.

Comment: Posting AI-generated answers is [forbidden on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).